# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel: last slide overlaps the first slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've got a problem with Bootstrap's Carousel: the last slide overlaps the first slide, when slides are wider than the Carousel div.

Jsfiddle, depicting the problem (scroll forward and watch how the last slide overlaps the first)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phan/ubwmS/)

```
"Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied be a code"
```

Also, I've noticed it just now, after the first time, when the carousel goes from last slide to first slide, the carousel-indicators stops highlighting the current slide number.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've work-arounded the problem with the help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038026/how-to-extend-twitter-bootstrap-image-carousel-for-dynamically-sized-centered-i).

The bottom line is, that I pushed the `<img>`es to css background for each `.carousel .item` and applied the following csses:

```
.carousel .item {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* background-size: cover; */ /* I don't wanna (up|down)scale */
    height: 510px; /* fixed height of the background images */
}

#carousel-item-1 {
    background-image: url(myImage.jpg);
}

#carousel-item-2 {
    background-image: url(myImage.jpg);
}

#carousel-item-3 {
    background-image: url(myImage.jpg);
}
```

A pleasurable side effect is that it also centers the images horizontally and vertically (crops them), which I also needed.

I think this way is the right way of doing this and I should have used it from the start. But I don't really like the fixed, handwritten `height: 510px`. I presume it will cause some headaches later, but well...

Answer (score 0):

In case of Bootstrap 3, I had the same issue when using old jQuery version (1.7). jQuery for Bootstrap 3 should be 1.9.1 or newer.